# signs of Messiah's imminent arrival

Tags: messiah

What are the main signs given by the sages that the Messiah's arrival is imminent and have those signs been fulfilled in our times?

Comment: everytime im on a bus here in E'Y and i see young kids not get up and give their seats to elders i see moshiach coming, chutzpah yazge

Comment: Why do you assume that such signs exist? This question could be improved by simply asking whether such signs exist (preferably with an explanation of you think they might).

Comment: ולעולם לא יתעסק אדם בדברי ההגדות, ולא יאריך בדברי מדרשות האמורים בעניינים אלו וכיוצא בהן; ולא ישימם עיקר--שאינן מביאין לא לידי אהבה, ולא לידי יראה.  וכן לא יחשב הקיצין; אמרו חכמים, תפוח דעתן של מחשבי קיצין.  אלא יחכה ויאמין בכלל הדבר, כמו שביארנו.

Comment: ויש מן החכמים שאומרים שקודם ביאת המלך המשיח, יבוא אלייהו.  וכל אלו הדברים וכיוצא בהן--לא יידע אדם היאך יהיו, עד שיהיו:  שדברים סתומים הן אצל הנביאים.  גם החכמים אין להם קבלה בדברים אלו

Answer (score 2):

The last Mishna in mesechet Sotah ([Ch9 Mishna 15](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%98%D7%94_%D7%98_%D7%98%D7%95) / [Daf 49b](http://mechon-mamre.org/b/l/l3509.htm)) deals with this:

> בעקבות משיחא חוצפא יסגא (תִרבה), ויוקר יאמיר: הגפן תתן פריה והיין
>   ביוקר, ומלכות תהפך למינות, ואין תוכחת, בית וועד יהיה לזנות, והגליל
>   יחרב, והגבלן (הגולן) יישום (יהיה ריק מאדם), ואנשי הגבול יסובבו מעיר
>   לעיר ולא יחוננו, וחכמות סופרים תסרח, ויראי חטא ימאסו, והאמת תהא נעדרת.
>   נערים פני זקנים ילבינו, זקנים יעמדו מפני קטנים, בן מנוול אב, בת קמה
>   באמה, כלה בחמותה, אויבי איש אנשי ביתו, פני הדור כפני הכלב, הבן אינו
>   מתבייש מאביו. ועל מה יש לנו להשען? על אבינו שבשמים.

(Soncino translation: (numbering mine) )

> In the footsteps of the messiah
>
> 1. Insolence will increase and honour dwindle;
> 2. the vine will yield its fruit [abundantly] but wine will be dear;
> 3. the government will turn to heresy and there will be none [to offer them] reproof;
> 4. the meeting-place [of scholars] will be used for immorality;
> 5. galilee will be destroyed, gablan desolated, and the dwellers on the frontier will go about [begging] from place to place without anyone to take pity on them;
> 6. the wisdom of the learned will degenerate, fearers of sin will be despised, and the truth will be lacking;
> 7. youths will put old men to shame, the old will stand up in the presence of the young, a son will revile his father, a daughter will
>      rise against her mother, a daughter-in-law against her mother-in-law,
>      and a man's enemies will be the members of his household;
> 8. the face of the generation will be like the face of a dog, a son will not feel ashamed before his father.
>
> So upon whom is it for us to rely? Upon our father who is in heaven.

Answer (score 1):

The [Talmud Sanhedrin 97b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=24&daf=97b&format=pdf):

> כלו כל הקיצין ואין הדבר תלוי אלא בתשובה ומעשים טובים
>
> All the signs of end times have finished and the matter is only dependent on Repentance.

The Talmud goes on to explain that there are two opinions about this repentance. One is that  it is inevitable, the other is that it is not.

The Rambam ([Teshuva 7:5](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=1&hilchos=5&perek=7&halocha=5&hilite=)) paskens like the former opinion:

> וכבר הבטיחה תורה שסוף ישראל לעשות תשובה בסוף גלותן ומיד הן נגאלין
>
> And the Torah already promised that in the end Israel will repent at the end of their exile and they will be immediately redeemed.

Comment: kitzin means signs? i think it means the "times"

Comment: @ray, Keitz means end.

Comment: ie all the calculated ends. potential dates. signs is "ot"

Comment: @ray, the signs are to indicate a time, as in the time is now. This posuk says this event means that Moshiach is coming at this time, etc. Otherwise, I'm not sure what your question is getting at.